# Camel CXF: IllegalArgumentException parameters should be of type X

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I'm working on a Camel project calling services with CXF.
The services are defined through a wsdl and which I cannot modify it.
I generated classes with wsdl2java: I will have many other remote services, they may change often, so I want to have the POJOs and interfaces to be generated as much as possible.

My generated interface looks like this:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr", name = "myService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface MyService {

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @WebResult(name = "sendMessageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr", partName = "parameters")
    @WebMethod
    SendMessageResponse sendLetter(
            @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "sendLetter", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr")
            SendLetter parameters
    ) throws MessageServiceException_Exception;

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @WebResult(name = "sendMessageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr", partName = "parameters")
    @WebMethod
    SendMessageResponse sendWebNotification(
            @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "sendWebNotification", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr")
            SendWebNotification parameters
    ) throws MessageServiceException_Exception;

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @WebResult(name = "sendMessageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr", partName = "parameters")
    @WebMethod
    SendMessageResponse sendEmail(
            @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "sendEmail", targetNamespace = "http://service.company.fr")
            SendEmail parameters
    ) throws MessageServiceException_Exception;
}
```

I defined the CXF Endpoint in an XML file, like this :

```
  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint"
                   address="http://localhost:9081/soap/service"
                   serviceClass="fr.company.service.MyService">
    <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO"/>
    </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And finally, I am calling the service in a Camel route :

```
from(URI_SERVICE)
                .process(sendEmailBodyProcessor)
                .to("cxf:bean:serviceEndpoint");
```

The `sendEmailBodyProcessor` sets the body with a SendEmail object (corresponding to the 3rd service from the interface). If I leave only the service I use in the interface, it works, but if I leave the other services, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://service.company.fr}parameters should be of type fr.company.service.SendLetter, not fr.company.service.SendEmail
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.checkPart(DataWriterImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    ...
```

I tried using headers like `operationName` or `method` etc. but I can't get it to work...

Has anyone a clue on how I can get it to work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to use the opertationName to specify which of the 3 operations to use, otherwise CXF will use the first it can find.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but like I said, I tried `operationName` and it was not enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to solve my problem!...

In my case, `operationName` was not enough, I needed to add `operationNamespace = "http://service.company.fr"` as well!